# Why does Tornado take so long to die when I hit ctrl-c?

Tags: python, tornado

When developing a Tornado application, I frequently want to restart the server to pick up new changes. I hit ctrl-c to stop the server, but with Tornado, this seems to be very slow. It waits for many seconds before shutting down, or doesn't shut down at all when issued a ctrl-c.

What's weird, is if, after clicking ctrl-c, I make a new request to the server (by, for example, refreshing my browser that is pointing at the server), it shuts down right away.

Anyone know how to explain this or fix it? Anyone experienced something similar?

(Note, this is on Windows.)

Comment: Is it a simple Tornado app, are you using in Database connectors or other modules for communications?  ctrl-c and threads have some interesting interactions, so it would be useful to know.

Comment: @koblas: I'm using websockets, but no database currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, signals are always handled by the main thread. If the IOLoop is run from the main thread, it will block it when server is idle and waiting for IO. As a result, all signals will be pending on the thread to wake up. That explains why sending a request shuts the server down.

UPDATE: You can try something like this:

```
def set_ping(ioloop, timeout):
    ioloop.add_timeout(timeout, lambda: set_ping(ioloop, timeout))
```

and then:

```
ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
set_ping(ioloop, timedelta(seconds=2))
ioloop.start()
```

when you start the loop. As a result, `select` will be called with 2.0 seconds timeout, preventing the blocking. (See also [IOLoop Timeouts](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/ioloop.html#timeouts))

(Note: I could not reproduce your situation on Linux, even though I manually set `select` to be used, so I cannot give 100% guarantee that this will help, but sounds plausible)

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, and makes some sense. I wonder if there's a way to get Tornado to periodically wake up its main thread without IO? If it could poll every second or so, that would fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it takes so long to exit with `Ctrl+C`, but it worked for me in some cases to press `Ctrl+\` (Linux terminal)

Answer (score 0):

add_timeout works; if you want to save on re-registering the timeout, instead you can do this:

```
ili=tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(lambda: None,500,ili).start()
ili.start()
```

Comment: Nowadays it's a little simpler:
```tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback( lambda:None, 1000 ).start()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()```